# Heroku sessions and passport.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js(passport-local) /mongodb. Locally works fine but when I deploy on heroku server feels like my session cannot be read or doesn't get saved for some reason.

Environment  NodeJs/Express.js

here is my environments:

**Passport Init :**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
        user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if(isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

**Express Environment:**

```
....
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(app.router);
```

Example of Use:

```
app.get('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, routes.admin);

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

So pretty much on heroku it always redirects me to `/login`

Thanks In Advice !

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using connect [MemoryStore](http://extjs.github.io/Connect/session.html), which is not suitable for production.

Instead, you want to use MongoDB, Postgres, or similar for a session store. By far the most popular is Redis, and [Redistogo](https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo#nano) has a free plan. Here's the info on [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis).